# Filter files according to owner under same directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am writing a script which has a common directory and under those directory there are some files with different owners.

How can I filter the files according to owner with their files and parse them separately with their owner name as filename:

```
/gen/comm_owner/a 
/gen/comm_owner/b
```

There are more than 20 owners with more than 60 files. expected output `gen/comm_owner/a.txt`,  where `a.txt` contains only his files, likewise for `b.txt`. I have tried `awk` and `sed` and I am able to filter some things but how to perform this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /some/path -type f -printf "%u/%P\n" | awk -F/ '{u=$1; sub($1"/", ""); print > u}'
```

- `find`'s `-printf` option is very powerful. In this case, I tell it to print the username and the relative file path separated by a slash (e.g., `muru/foo/bar` (or you could use `%p` instead of `%P`, for `muru//some/path/foo/bar`).
- Then, in `awk`, splitting on `/`, I save the first field (the username), remove it from the input, and then print the input to that username.

Example:

```
$ find /var/lib -type f -printf "%u/%p\n" | awk -F/ '{u=$1; sub($1"/", ""); print > u}'                                              
$ ls
colord  nobody  ntp  ptokax  root  systemd-timesync
$ head ntp
/var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
$ head nobody
/var/lib/nfs/state
$ head root
/var/lib/dbus/machine-id
/var/lib/os-prober/labels
/var/lib/xkb/README.compiled
/var/lib/logrotate.status
/var/lib/nfs/rmtab
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `-user` test to `find` and pass your usernames to it with a loop. Here's an example with just two users:

```
for users in zanna pixie; do find /gen -type f -user "$users"  > /gen/comm_owner/"$users".txt ; done
```

`zanna` and `pixie` are users on my system. This creates two files called `zanna.txt` with a text list of files owned by `zanna`, and `pixie.txt` with a text list of files owned by `pixie`

The filenames in the files are exactly in the form reported by `find` with this example, but you could adjust this, for example you could `-exec basename '{}' \;` before the redirection to avoid having the full path.